# Prevent executing query for wp_global_styles

Tags: query, full-site-editing

I'm inspecting a site I'm maintaining using query monitor plugin and I noticed this query being executed:

```sql
SELECT
    wp_posts.ID
FROM
    wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (32))
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wp_global_styles'
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY
    wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY
    wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT
    0, 1
```

Now, it's not a taxing query or anything, but I'm not using FSE so I don't need to check for any global styles or other FSE functionality.

Is there a way to prevent this query from being run?

The caller stack is:

```
WP_Query->get_posts()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3156
WP_Query->query()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3613
get_posts()
wp-includes/post.php:2410
wp_get_recent_posts()
wp-includes/post.php:3939
WP_Theme_JSON_Resolver::get_user_data_from_wp_global_styles()
wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json-resolver.php:285
WP_Theme_JSON_Resolver::get_user_data()
wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json-resolver.php:323
WP_Theme_JSON_Resolver::get_merged_data()
wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json-resolver.php:387
{closure}()
wp-includes/script-loader.php:3076
{closure}()
wp-includes/script-loader.php:3272
do_action('wp_loaded')
wp-includes/plugin.php:476
```

and I've done some digging, but didn't find a filter to prevent this query from being run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a somewhat old question, but it's a good one that doesn't have an answer, so here goes...

---

The first feasible/sensible entry point to all the above code in the call stack is the `_wp_theme_json_webfonts_handler` function, defined in `wp-includes/script-loader.php`.

The function is hooked to `plugins_loaded`, as per `wp-includes/default-filters.php`.

So, if you don't use a block or hybrid or full-site editing theme, you can unhook the callback and you should be good.

For example, like so:

```php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {

    remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', '_wp_theme_json_webfonts_handler' );
}, 0 );
```

Please note that the `_wp_theme_json_webfonts_handler` function is considered *private*, and it will get replaced in a future version of WordPress (see [comment](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1.1/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L3159-L3186)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer 